# Добавить namespace'ы в XML-блоки

Tags: xml, sql-server

Здравствуйте! Имеется следующий тэмплэйт:

```
 <PersonalProgramList>  
        <PersonalProgram>
            <One>randomInfo</One>
            <Two>randomInfo</Two>
        </PersonalProgram>
        <PersonalProgram>
            <One>randomInfo</One>
            <Two>randomInfo</Two>
        </PersonalProgram>
        <PersonalProgram>
            <One>randomInfo</One>
            <Two>randomInfo</Two>
        </PersonalProgram>
    </PersonalProgramList>
```

Как, используя T-SQL превратить его в:

```
 <tns:PersonalProgramList xmlns:tns="http://example.com/blalba/">
    <PersonalProgram xmlns="http://example.com/blalba/">
        <One>randomInfo</One>
        <Two>randomInfo</Two>
    </PersonalProgram>
    <PersonalProgram xmlns="http://example.com/blalba/">
        <One>randomInfo</One>
        <Two>randomInfo</Two>
    </PersonalProgram>
    <PersonalProgram xmlns="http://example.com/blalba/">
        <One>randomInfo</One>
        <Two>randomInfo</Two>
    </PersonalProgram>
</tns:PersonalProgramList>
```

`PersonalProgramList` - корень, `PersonalProgram` - неограниченное кол-во.

Comment: @i-one, не пойдёт.

Comment: Внутри `PersonalProgram` может быть только то, что в вопросе (только `One` и `Two` с текстом внутри), или что угодно?

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть ваш запрос, которым вы получаете такой XML. Или у вас исходные данные содержат XML, вам нужно только добавить namespace?

Comment: @i-one, что угодно, даже неограниченное кол-во блоков, вложенных друг в друга.

Comment: @minamoto, готовая XML, надо её просто приправить namespace'ми.
Дело в том, что в `PersonalProgram` может быть вложено неограниченное кол-во блоков, а в эти вложенные блоки - ещё другие блоки. Мне надо в рут дать namespace и в каждый блок `PersonalProgram`, не затрагивая при этом вложенные в него блоки.

Comment: Можете [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35657736/5045688) вариант с реплейсом посмотреть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой способ заменить *namespace* элемента (средствами XQuery) мне неизвестен.

Если бы исходная схема XML была именно такая как в вопросе (внутри *PersonalProgram* могут быть только *One* и *Two* с каким-то текстом внутри), то можно было бы честно пересобрать исходный XML в нужном формате с помощью [FLWOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190945.aspx):

```
declare @xml xml = N'<PersonalProgramList>...';

select
    @xml.query(N'
        <tns:PersonalProgramList xmlns:tns="http://example.com/blalba/">
        {
            for $pp in /PersonalProgramList/PersonalProgram
                return
                    <PersonalProgram xmlns="http://example.com/blalba/">
                    {
                        for $a in $pp/*
                            return if (local-name($a) = "One")
                                then <One>{$a/text()}</One>
                                else <Two>{$a/text()}</Two>
                    }
                    </PersonalProgram>
        }
        </tns:PersonalProgramList>');
```

Если же внутри *PersonalProgram* может быть что угодно, то можно так же с помощью FLWOR пересобрать XML, указав нужный *namespace* для *PersonalProgram*, и скопировав всё что внутри. Однако при замене *namespace* для *PersonalProgram* у всего что внутри явно укажется `xmlns=""`, который кроме как с помощью `REPLACE` я не вижу варианта убрать (поэтому мне этот способ не очень нравится):

```
select
    cast(replace(cast(@xml.query(N'
        <tns:PersonalProgramList xmlns:tns="http://example.com/blalba/">
        {
            for $pp in /PersonalProgramList/PersonalProgram
                return
                    <PersonalProgram xmlns="http://example.com/blalba/">
                    {
                        $pp/*
                    }
                    </PersonalProgram>
        }
        </tns:PersonalProgramList>') as nvarchar(max)), N'xmlns=""', N'') as xml);
```

Comment: А как вы рассматриваете вариант реплэйса нужных тэгов без юзанья FLWOR? XML в VARCHAR(MAX) и замена `<PersonalProgram>` на `<PersonalProgram xmlns="http://example.com/blalba/">`, правда потом придётся это ещё в `REPLACE` завернуть, чтобы рут поменять.

Comment: @Knack, если внутри `PersonalProgram` не могут быть вложенные `PersonalProgram` и `PersonalProgramList`, то да - можно обойтись несколькими `REPLACE`. Также нужно учесть, могут ли быть пустые `<PersonalProgram/>`.

Comment: вложенных `<PersonalProgram>` и пустых `<PersonalProgram/>` быть не может. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить вам вариант с добавлением дефалтового namespace на корневой уровень.

Предположим, у вас такая структура таблиц:

```
create table PersonalProgram (One nvarchar(max), Two nvarchar(max));

insert into PersonalProgram values ('randomIfo', 'randomIfo');
```

Тогда запрос будет такой:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://example.com/blalba/' as tns,
                    default 'http://example.com/blalba/')  
select *
from PersonalProgram
for xml path('PersonalProgram'), root('tns:PersonalProgramList')
```

Если же вам принципиально дефалтовый namespace добавить не на корневой уровень, тогда будет немного сложнее вариант, сейчас навскидку не готов ответить.